# How do I use Putty to connect to my 16 slot GSM modem?

Tags: mobile, com, serial-port, gsm

Hello I have recently got a 16-slot GSM Modem which I have been trying to connect to with Putty thought its serial connector it only connects to one USB port. I was wondering if I need to emulate COM ports since Putty won't let me type anything when I connect to the specified COM ports in the device manager.

Comment: I don't know what device you are talking about ([this one?](https://it.aliexpress.com/i/32859905437.html)) Could you specify vendor and model by editing your question? Talking about your issue: have you correctly set the baudrate and the other settings of the serial connection?

Comment: It is "FIMT 16/32/64 ports bulk GSM SMS Modem" sold by "GUO JUE ELECTRONICS"

Comment: I cannot find a guide of this device. So I con only provide some general suggestions: 1) make sure the device is turned on!, 2) make sure that the putty settings (baudrate, flow control, bit settings) match those of the device

Comment: Hello, I have tried that but I am not having any luck do you know if I need to emulate COM Ports?